# IPhone push notfication for a webapp?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, iphone-web-app, iphone-standalone-web-app

Is it possible to implement IPhone's push notification service for a 
Webapp that has an icon on the "desktop"? If so how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That depends on exactly what you mean by *Webapp that has an icon on the "desktop"?*

**No**, if you're referring to a webapp where you have saved a link with *Add to Home screen* [as per this Apple instruction](http://www.apple.com/webapps/whatarewebapps.html).

**Yes**, if your webapp is a thin CocoaTouch shell using [webkit](http://drnicwilliams.com/2008/11/10/to-webkit-or-not-to-webkit-within-your-iphone-app/).

Answer (score 3):

i have an alternative solution for this:

1) create a gmail account and get gpush app on your iphone (setup the gmail in the app).

2) instate of sending direct notification to iphone, you can send an email from your webapp to the gmail account.

3) within 5 sec. you will receive the push notification.

hope this help.

Comment: Ok, bit of an oldie but anyhow. it's still an interesting question. this requires the user to get gpsuh?

Answer (score 3):

You can always delegate the messaging to 3rd party notification apps.
One great example is Boxcar (http://boxcar.io/).
You can have your web app send notifications via their API and have them delivered to the app. Lastly, you can the use deeplinks in your message to open your webapp to point the user to the content item you wanted to bring their attention to.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. It's only for cocoa touch (AppStore) apps. If you want more info, take a look on the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

another alternative: use an sms service like http://www.smstrade.de/ to send an sms to the user's phone. That's the way I do it.

Answer (score 1):

Another provider for sending sms as notification is https://bulktrade.de 
There works world wide

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 to introduce your own push messages. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets)

> "For the client side, WebSocket was to be implemented in Firefox 4,
>   Google Chrome 4, Opera 11, and Safari 5, as well as the mobile version
>   of Safari in iOS 4.2.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) Also the BlackBerry Browser in OS7 supports
>   WebSockets."

To do this, you need your own provider server to push the messages to the clients. 
If you want to use APN (Apple Push Notification), you must have a native application which must be downloaded through the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 6.0 I noticed that a WebApp icon placed on homescreen automaticly refreshes after each webkit open of webapp. Of course if you change this icon on the webserver. So theoretically you can display any informative content in this icon(numbers, status etc) BUT it will not refreshes instantly - only after opening and closing a webkit webapp.